# permission denied error while writting in empty csv file

Tags: python

PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     62 tweetDataFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\tweetDataFile.csv"
     63 
---> 64 trainingData = buildTrainingSet(corpusFile, tweetDataFile)
     65 
     66 # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

in buildTrainingSet(corpusFile, tweetDataFile)
     48             continue
     49     # Now we write them to the empty CSV file
---> 50     with open(tweetDataFile,'wt') as csvfile:
     51         linewriter=csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar="\"")
     52         for tweet in trainingDataSet:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\tweetDataFile.csv'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file tweetDataFile.csv open at the same time (e.g. in Excel?). If yes, pandas cannot write on it.